# I have some issue when I install openpose Pyhon build

Tags: python, visual-c++, cmake, openpose

First, my env.

1. Python 3.11.x (newst)
2. Visual enterprise 2022 (I install C++ component what I know that)
3. Window 10 - recently reset.
4. Cuda 12.1 with cuDNN for 12.x (all recent ver. since I reset the PC)

Situation.

1. I clone github
   git clone https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose
   as introduced in openpose.
2. after I update submodules.
   git submodule update --init --recursive --remote
3. generate directory \build
4. cmake-gui .. -> configulation. (with visual 2022 17) -> after checking my build_python box -> configulation once again.

Then, I face this set-up where my co-worker didn't see before.
[pybind11_cpp_standard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61AHn.png)

5. First, I didn't care because i already install pybind11 in my virtual anaconda env.
6. After generate -> open project. -> build solution with "release"
7. Build failed. for pyopenpose.vcxproj with problem.
   Undefined "sszie_t"

Here's my trial

At 5, Configulation again -> generate.
But, build was also fail.

At 7, I realize that pybind11's numpy.h has about that code. "sszie_t"

I simple def SSZIE_t sszie_t

For that case, build was ok.

But run the example of openpose has error

Exception: Error: OpenPose library could not be found. Did you enable BUILD_PYTHON in CMake and have this Python script in the right folder?

I don't knw what to do anymore..

Did I miss something? Did I forget some C++ components?

Comment: Please include full, exact error messages with tracebacks.

Comment: IDK. it's fixed for some PC but others.

make sure following those who face this type of problem.

(1) Make sure install the CUDA completely. If there is not installed one, please check that.
(2) Make sure you're working about the CuDNN.
(3) Do not use blank at pc names.
(4) Make sure all C++ component is installed.
(5) Make sure Cmake is installed correct version.
(6) Make sure all the paths are ok.